# Data Output Rates for dsPIC Microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, pic, spi, microchip

I'm designing a high throughput data collection and transmission device, and I'm currently looking at the dsPIC33CH128MP202 as the central device. I have one signal that I am converting to a digital signal, and alternating between the main core and secondary core ADC modules to increase my sampling rate. After conversion, the conversion data needs to be output to an external transmitter to be read by a central data collection device. When looking through the data sheet, I see the SPI module as the fastest option with a maximum clock speed of 40 MHz. While I have an ADC sample rate that can work with this, the ADC modules are capable of higher sampling rates. As a result, I feel limited by the output rate of the SPI module. I have included a basic graphic of what I'm working with below.

Is there a way to achieve a faster data output rate than the 40 MHz of the SPI in the dsPIC device? For instance, could an external device access data in the dsPIC via one of the DMA modules? If so, would that be based on the MIPS of the dsPIC device and/or the MIPS of the data collection device/transmitter?

The other issue that I've run into with this is the limited number of SPI modules. I'd like to be able to use more than just two of the four ADC modules in the dsPIC. If there are other methods of exporting the data, that could solve this issue as well. In this case, I would be looking at using the secondary core for data conversion (3 ADC modules) and the main core for data output. In this scenario, would it require one instruction to send a bit to the MSI module, one instruction to read the bit into the main core, then further instruction cycles to output that data?

Thank you all for taking the time to read through my questions, and I appreciate any guidance you all may have.

[image]

Edit:
As questions pop up, I'll try to answer them here.

> What kind of transmitting device are you planning on using which supports those sorts of data rates?

The transmitting device and network protocol haven't been selected yet as I'm still in the early stages of the design process. I'm picturing a dedicated SoC device, but that will depend on the network protocol that I use.

> Just so we have the whole picture, how many samples per second do you need to send?

The ADC modules on the dsPIC device have a maximum sample rate of 3.5 MSPS. I'm looking at setting a trigger for 3 MSPS on 2 or 3 ADC cores in the secondary MCU core. The ADC cores will have offset triggers for an effective sampling rate of 6-9 MSPS.

> Also, are you doing anything less than bright like trying to send ASCII? Forgive my asking, but this does happen, without people realizing that sending binary could make problems go away.

The data will be coming directly from the internal ADC cores, which is in the form of a 16-bit word. From my understanding, the data is stored in binary in the ADCBUFx register.

> Last point, 40MHz is your SPI Clock, not the SPI data rate. I'm going to assume that the SPI word to be sent is at least 8 bits, so your data rate is going to be no faster than 5MHz.

Yes, that's what I was realizing this afternoon. The ADC outputs a 16-bit word, which would only result in an output rate of 2.5 MSPS. The dsPIC device only has 3 SPI modules as well: 2 in the main core (1 with 40 MHz maximum clock and 1 with 15 MHz clock) and 1 in the secondary core with a 40 MHz maximum clock.

Comment: What kind of transmitting device are you planning on using which supports those sorts of data rates?

Comment: Just so we have the whole picture, how many samples per second do you need to send?

Comment: Also, are you doing anything less than bright like trying to send ASCII?  Forgive my asking, but this does happen, without people realizing that sending binary could make problems go away.

Comment: Last point, 40MHz is your SPI Clock, not the SPI data rate.  I'm going to assume that the SPI word to be sent is at least 8 bits, so your data rate is going to be no faster than 5MHz.

Comment: Thank you @brhans for your comment. I've posted your question in the main post above, along with my answers.

Comment: Thank you @ScottSeidman for your comments. I've posted your questions in the main post above, along with my answers.